# [Python]Spliting the elements of csv file and inserting in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, csv, insert

I have a csv file which looks like this:

```
UnifiedSearch_Pass,UnifiedSearch_Fail,Settings_Pass,Settings_Fail,Map_Overview_Pass,Map_Overview_Fail,Map_Guidance_Pass,Map_Guidance_Fail,RouteBar_Pass,RouteBar_Fail,MainMenu_Pass,MainMenu_Fail,SpeedCameras_Pass,SpeedCameras_Fail,MapManagement_Pass,MapManagement_Fail,AccountManagement_Pass,AccountManagement_Fail,VoiceManagement_Pass,VoiceManagement_Fail,Total_Automated_Tests,Total_Pass,Total_Fail
177,8,57,5,90,6,48,3,48,6,109,12,17,2,14,0,12,0,10,0,624,582,4
```

And Here is the code for the mysql insertion:

```
for row in csv_data:
print row
print row[0]
    sql = "INSERT INTO 'EpicDetails' ('EpicName', 'Result') VALUES (?, ?);"
    cursor.execute (sql, (row[0]))
```

This give me TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting.

Printing row, prints all the elements in the csv file.
Printing row[0] gives this:

```
UnifiedSearch_Pass
177
```

I need to insert the value above in row[0] in two different column.

Any help will be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: in your insert statement you have 2 column but you are passing only one value

Comment: Can you tell me which 2 fields from csv file you wish to insert ?

Comment: Im guessing you would want to insert the name of each field with the associated number?  so like UnifiedSearch_Pass with 177?

Comment: @Backtrack, I wan to insert values of row[0] in two different column. i.e. 'UnifiedSearch_Pass' should go into column name 'EpicName' and '177' in Results column.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the specific row put in separate columns

```
sql = (
 "INSERT INTO 'EpicDetails' ('EpicName', 'Result') VALUES (?, ?);"
 )
 data = (row[0][0],row[0][1])
 cursor.execute(sql, data)
```

Comment: I tried this it gives me ; TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting



 cursor.execute(sql, data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 187, in execute
    query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])

I tried to do some changes in sql query but then it takes only the first character in table. i.e 'U' in EpicName and 1 in 'Result';

Comment: print row[0][0], row[0][1]

gives:  U n
1 7

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("../input/pathtofile.csv")

clmn_names = df.columns


for row  in df.itertuples():
    print(df.columns[0],getattr(row,'UnifiedSearch_Pass'))

    sql = "INSERT INTO 'EpicDetails' ('EpicName', 'Result') VALUES (?, ?);"
    cursor.execute (sql, (df.columns[0],getattr(row,'UnifiedSearch_Pass'))
```

try some thing like this.  I am using Pandas to read csv file.  From your comment I understand that you watn to inser column name as a filed.